# How to put unicode char into NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsstring

For example I could type an emoji character code such as:

```
NSString* str = @"";
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

The smile emoji would be seen in the console.

Maybe the code editor and the compiler would trade the literal in UTF-8.

And now I'm working in a full unicode, I mean 32bit per char, environment and I've got the unicode of the emoji, I want to convert the 32bit unicode into a NSString for example:

```
int charcode = 0x0001F60A;
NSLog(@"%??", charcode);
```

The question is what should I put at the "??" position and then I could format the charcode into a emoji string?

BTW the charcode was a variable which can not be determine at the compile time.

I don't want to compress the 32bit int into UTF-8 bytes unless that would be the only way.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean or what your question is, but you can use `@"\U0001F60A"`

Comment: The char code was dynamic for example read from DB or somewhere else

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `0x0001F60A` is a dynamic value determined at runtime then
you can use the `NSString` method

```
- (instancetype)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)len encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding;
```

to create a string containing a character with the given Unicode value:

```
int charcode = 0x0001F60A;
uint32_t data = OSSwapHostToLittleInt32(charcode); // Convert to little-endian
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&data length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@", str); //
```

Comment: Thanks man. I've been looking for the solution for a long time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NSString` initialization method

```
int charcode = 0x0001F60A;
NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&charcode length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding]);
```